# c++ unit testing using c#

Tags: c++, testing

I have MFC dlls and I would like to test it using C#.
I guess testing c++ with c++ code is more natural but I would rather work on C# whenever possible.
Is there a built in solution in Visual Studio that i can use without installing 3rd party framework?

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to mess with PInvoke calls from C# in order to do this?  If not, check out WinUnit, it's pretty easy once you get it set up.  Definitely not as nice as the integrated VS test app, but it does the job until VS 11 comes out with native support

Answer (score 0):

Should probably just bite the bullet and use CPP testing framework: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419385.aspx

Now assuming you're reason for avoiding C++ is good, and not just a fear that's going to cause you more pain than gain, I'd suggest a CLI layer.  Of course then you have to write that.. but it can be pretty darn basic.  And when you run your tests you are testing both the layer and the wrapped method, but this is going to be true of any Interop layer (hence why the CPP testing framework should be your default choice).

I would avoid COM Interop.  PInvoke is probably messy too, but for trivial cases might be the easiest.